# Saving Outlook Message Using "docx" Format With C#

Tags: c#, outlook, interop, save, docx

I use this code to save my mail message as a `.doc` file using interop :

```
mailItem.SaveAs(newFileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olDoc);
```

Now I have to save it as `.docx` but there is no `OlSaveAsType.olDocx` so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i write a class to convert office 2003 to 2007 documents. I hope it will be useful for someone :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace Sobiens.Connectors.Common
{
    public static class officeConverter
    {
        public enum officeApplication { Word, Excel, PowerPoint };

        private static Dictionary<string, officeDestination> destinationDictionary = new Dictionary<string, officeDestination> {
        {".doc",new officeDestination(officeApplication.Word,".docx",Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument)},
        {".dot",new officeDestination(officeApplication.Word,".dotx",Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFlatXMLTemplate)},
        {".xls",new officeDestination(officeApplication.Excel,".xlsx",Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook)},
        {".xlt",new officeDestination(officeApplication.Excel,".xltx",Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLTemplate)},
        {".ppt",new officeDestination(officeApplication.PowerPoint,".pptx",PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation)},
        {".pot",new officeDestination(officeApplication.PowerPoint,".potx",PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenXMLTemplate)}
        };

        public static bool convertToNewOfficeDocument(string fileName, out string newFileName)
        {
            string ext;
            return convertToNewOfficeDocument(fileName, out newFileName, out ext);
        }

        public static bool convertToNewOfficeDocument(string fileName, out string newFileName, out string newExt)
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            newExt = ext;


            newFileName = fileName;


            if (!destinationDictionary.ContainsKey(ext)) return false;

            officeDestination dest = destinationDictionary[ext];
            newExt = dest.Extension;

            newFileName = fileName.Replace(ext, dest.Extension);

            object obj;

            bool result = true;

            switch (dest.Application)
            {
                case officeApplication.Word:
                    Word._Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
                    Word._Document wordDoc = null;

                    try
                    {
                        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName);
                        wordDoc.Convert();
                        wordDoc.SaveAs(newFileName, dest.FileFormat);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        displayError(fileName, e);
                        newFileName = fileName;
                        result = false;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        wordDoc.Close();
                        wordApp.Quit();
                        obj = (object)wordDoc;
                        disposeInteropObject(ref obj);
                        obj = (object)wordApp;
                        disposeInteropObject(ref obj);
                    }
                    break;
                case officeApplication.Excel:
                    Excel._Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                    Excel._Workbook excelDoc = null;
                    try
                    {
                        excelDoc = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
                        excelDoc.SaveAs(newFileName, dest.FileFormat);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        displayError(fileName, e);
                        newFileName = fileName;
                        result = false;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        excelDoc.Close();
                        excelApp.Quit();
                        obj = (object)excelDoc;
                        disposeInteropObject(ref obj);
                        obj = (object)excelApp;
                        disposeInteropObject(ref obj);                        
                    }
                    break;
                case officeApplication.PowerPoint:
                    PowerPoint._Application powerpointApp = new PowerPoint.Application();
                    PowerPoint._Presentation powerpointDoc = null;
                    try
                    {
                        powerpointDoc = powerpointApp.Presentations.Open(fileName, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
                        powerpointDoc.SaveAs(newFileName, (PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType)dest.FileFormat);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        displayError(fileName, e);
                        newFileName = fileName;
                        result = false;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        powerpointDoc.Close();
                        powerpointApp.Quit();
                        obj = (object)powerpointDoc;
                        disposeInteropObject(ref obj);
                        obj = (object)powerpointApp;
                        disposeInteropObject(ref obj);
                    }
                    break;


            }

            GC.Collect();
            return result;
        }

        private static void displayError(string fileName, Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Le fichier \"" + fileName + "\" n'à pu être converti\n" + e.Message,
            "Erreur", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// dispose interop object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="o">object to dispose</param>
        private static void disposeInteropObject(ref object o)
        {
            if (o != null)
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o);
            o = null;
        }

        private class officeDestination
        {
            public officeApplication Application;
            public string Extension;
            public object FileFormat;

            public officeDestination(officeApplication application, string extension, object fileFormat)
            {
                Application = application;
                Extension = extension;
                FileFormat = fileFormat;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to automate the Word application.

[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

It has special `WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault` enumeration. For Word 2007, this is the DOCX format.

You should open doc file `Documents.Open` and then use `Documents.Save` and and  `Documents.Close` to save a file.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to convert my doc. This is not the more elegant way but it work

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document document = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileName);

            fileName = fileName.ToLower().Replace(".doc", ".docx");
            document.Convert();
            document.SaveAs(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatXMLDocument);
            document.Close();
            document = null;
```

thanks to all.